# How can I make l5-swagger generate docs using both annotations and attributes?

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, openapi

I am using Laravel for the project, I've got documentation written in annotations but I want to change everything to attributes. Whenever I do some changes and generate docs, all the new things written in attributes don't get generated, but docs written using annotations do. L5-Swagger and OpenApi are both up-to-date, am I supposed to change anything in other files as  well? Thank you in advance.